# Python Rolling 30 day period GROUP By with Count Distinct String

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset of 'user_name','mac','dayte'(day). I would like to GROUP BY ['user_name']. Then for that GROUP BY create WINDOW of rolling 30 days using 'dayte'. In that rolling 30 day period, I would like to count the distinct number of 'mac'. And add that to my dataframe. Sample of the data.

```
    user_name mac   dayte
0   001j    7C:D1   2017-09-15
1   0039711 40:33   2017-07-25
2   0459    F0:79   2017-08-01
3   0459    F0:79   2017-08-06
4   0459    F0:79   2017-08-31
5   0459    78:D7   2017-09-08
6   0459    E0:C7   2017-09-16
7   133833  18:5E   2017-07-27
8   133833  F4:0F   2017-07-31
9   133833  A4:E4   2017-08-07
```

I have tried solving this with a PANDAs dataframe.

```
df['ct_macs'] = df.groupby(['user_name']).rolling('30d', on='dayte').mac.apply(lambda x:len(x.unique()))
```

But received the error

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

I tried in PySpark, but received an error as well.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#function to calculate number of seconds from number of days
days = lambda i: i * 86400

#convert string timestamp to timestamp type             
df= df.withColumn('dayte', df.dayte.cast('timestamp')) 
#create window by casting timestamp to long (number of seconds)
w = Window.partitionBy("user_name").orderBy("dayte").rangeBetween(-days(30), 0)

df= df.select("user_name","mac","dayte",F.size(F.denseRank().over(w).alias("ct_mac")))
```

But received the error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o464.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function dense_rank does not take a frame specification.;
```

I also tried

```
df= df.select("user_name","dayte",F.countDistinct(col("mac")).over(w).alias("ct_mac"))
```

But it's (count distinct in Window) not supported, apparently, in Spark.
I'm open to a purely SQL approach. In either MySQL or SQL Server, but would prefer Python or Spark.

Answer (score 1):

**Pyspark**

Window functions are limited in the following ways:

- A frame can only be defined by rows and not column values
- `countDistinct` doesn't exist
- enumerating functions cannot be used with a frame

Instead you can self join your table.

First let's create the dataframe:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([["001j", "7C:D1", "2017-09-15"], ["0039711", "40:33", "2017-07-25"], ["0459", "F0:79", "2017-08-01"], 
                    ["0459", "F0:79", "2017-08-06"], ["0459", "F0:79", "2017-08-31"], ["0459", "78:D7", "2017-09-08"], 
                    ["0459", "E0:C7", "2017-09-16"], ["133833", "18:5E", "2017-07-27"], ["133833", "F4:0F", "2017-07-31"], 
                    ["133833", "A4:E4", "2017-08-07"]]).toDF(["user_name", "mac", "dayte"])
```

Now for the `join` and `groupBy`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.alias("left")\
    .join(
        df.alias("right"), 
        (psf.col("left.user_name") == psf.col("right.user_name")) 
        & (psf.col("right.dayte").between(psf.date_add("left.dayte", -30), psf.col("left.dayte"))), 
        "leftouter")\
    .groupBy(["left." + c for c in df.columns])\
    .agg(psf.countDistinct("right.mac").alias("ct_macs"))\
    .sort("user_name", "dayte").show()

    +---------+-----+----------+-------+
    |user_name|  mac|     dayte|ct_macs|
    +---------+-----+----------+-------+
    |     001j|7C:D1|2017-09-15|      1|
    |  0039711|40:33|2017-07-25|      1|
    |     0459|F0:79|2017-08-01|      1|
    |     0459|F0:79|2017-08-06|      1|
    |     0459|F0:79|2017-08-31|      1|
    |     0459|78:D7|2017-09-08|      2|
    |     0459|E0:C7|2017-09-16|      3|
    |   133833|18:5E|2017-07-27|      1|
    |   133833|F4:0F|2017-07-31|      2|
    |   133833|A4:E4|2017-08-07|      3|
    +---------+-----+----------+-------+
```

**Pandas**

This works for python3

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df["mac"] = pd.factorize(df["mac"])[0]
df.groupby('user_name').rolling('30D', on="dayte").mac.apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)))
```

Comment: I am scratching my head on how to count distinct categorical variable in rolling time window in Pandas. it works if we factorize first. It doesn't work if we doesnt factorize. Why so? Please please let me know. @MaFF